# QGIS Error- Layer ELRreal: OGR[3] error 1: REPACK of layer 'ELRreal' failed?

Tags: qgis, hebrew

anytime I try to save my shapefille after editing it I get the next error messege-

> Layer ELRreal: OGR[3] error 1: REPACK of layer 'ELRreal' failed.

I don't know if it's relevant but the attribute table has data in hebrew.

Does anyone know what this error means and how to deal with it?

Comment: The first test to do is to edit a shapefile that has attributes in English and try if you can save that.